# Getting error on Evernote listNotebooks API - Javascript / Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, evernote

My web app in importing Evernote notebooks of a user to visualize them as a network.

Everything works fine with a sandbox version, but once I try to do it on the production server, when I do

noteStore.listNotebooks

I get the following err:

{ errorCode: 8,
  message: 'authenticationToken',
  rateLimitDuration: null }

You can see the code on https://github.com/noduslabs/infranodus/blob/evernote/routes/imports.js#L428

My developer API is activated on the main server (at least I requested it a few months ago and received a confirmation of that). My developer API username is infranodus.

ALso, the oAuthAccessToken also seems to be obtained and transmitted inside my app.

Could you please tell me why this error pops up and how can I extract the notebook list – both private and public ones for the user?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

How did you get the token ? Is it a dev token or an oauth one ?
In both cases make sure that they were issued by the production server and not the sandbox one (i.e. you can't use a sandbox token in production environment).

If it's a prod token, I'd suggest to open a support ticket asking the Evernote team to check your credentials : https://dev.evernote.com/support/  (manage an api key)

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion : get a prod token (https://www.evernote.com/api/DeveloperToken.action) and use it instead of your oauth token. If it works then you have a problem with your API key (and you should open a support ticket as suggested above). If it does not work then there's an issue with your code.